# Define similar methods at once

Tags: ruby

I've seen things like

```
[:toto, :tata, :titi].each do |kind|
    if "create_#{kind}" do
        something
    end
end
```

where the methods `create_toto`, `create_tata`, and `create_titi` are defined elsewhere.

I was wondering if it's possible to do it with method definitions. I have multiple methods named `end_{something}`, which do the same thing, and I would like to know if it's possible to group them into one, with the same mechanism as above.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Ruby to me. Could you double-check and/or perhaps link to where you have seen this, because it is not that clear what you want to do (you cannot use "same mechanism as above" as it doesn't appear to do anything). I *think* you want to define a bunch of very similar methods in a loop, which is something that Ruby can do. But about the only thing about that like your example is the first line . . . which is just the loop definition

Comment: @NeilSlater actually I can't link because it's a work program and it's not on this computer. What I meant by "same mechanism" was the "create_{kind}" which substitues each loop another kind and call the good function. I was wondering if I could have something like `def end_{kind}` and somewhere have kind = [:titi, :toto]. If it's possible to do something like that in ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take notice the expression `if "create_#{kind}"` will always return true, you probably mean `defined?("create_#{kind}")` which checks if a method is defined.

you can use the 'method_missing' method:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
  method = method_name.to_s 

  case method
  when 'create_toto'
    #do somthing
  when 'create_tata'
    #do somthing
  when 'create_titi'
    #do somthing
  else
    super
  end
end
```

You can also define methods dynamically:

```
[:toto, :tata, :titi].each do |kind|
  define_method "create_#{kind}" do
    #do something
  end
end
```